# prove that $n >2$ and $n$ is a prime then $n$ is odd

Tags: prime-numbers

$n > 2$ and $n$ is a prime number then $n$ is odd.

Prove by contradiction
assume $n$ is even
then there is some $k\in\Bbb N, n = 2k$
then $n >2, 2k > 2 , k > 1$

Is this  a sufficient proof?

Comment: What is your contradiction? $k>1$?  You have the right idea but remember what **prime** means.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Im trying to say n is not a prime since it is divisible by 2

Comment: How do you define a prime number and why is 2 a prime number?

Comment: prime number has only two factors, itself and 1  2= (1)(2) I understand the concept but I dont know how to prove it

Comment: And your other even prime candidate $n=2k$, which factors does it have?

Comment: The factors are 2 and k

Comment: @user105696 That is a terrible definition of prime. Note that $-1|2, -2|2, 1|2, \ \mathrm{and}\ 2|2$, so by your definition $nothing$ is prime.  Moreover, what would you say is a prime number in the Gaussian integers?

EDIT: sorry, not trying to be mean, but there are definitely more elegant and general ways of defining a prime number

Comment: Relax this proof is for an introductory course... so this definition is sufficient and n > 2 so your point is invalid

Comment: But you haven't arrived at (or explicitly stated) a contradiction!

Comment: @amWhy exactly that is what I am trying to figure out with your help....

Comment: @Tim.Ratigan: divisibility by only $1$ and itself seems to me a good enough definition as longer as we are sure we are on $\Bbb N$ (and itself$\ne1$).  Negative divisors are excluded from $\Bbb N$.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón How would I actually show this by using what I have so far??

Answer (score 2):

To write a proof by contradiction, you must assume the premise and the negation of the conclusion:

Assume there exists an **even** prime $n > 2$. So $n = 2k$ where $k>1$ is an integer. (Here you can use your work showing why $k$ must be greater than 1).

Hence $n$ has at least two factors greater than or equal to $2$: $2,$ and $k \geq 2$. Hence...

Comment: Hence n is even but this contradicts the fact that n>2 and n is a prime number since n =2(k) and k>=2

Comment: The fact that $n$ has two or more factors greater than or equal to $2$ contradicts the premise that $n$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

In your proof,because $n>2$ then $k\geq 2$ and thus $n$ has at least two factors grater than 2